# Check right installation of 7-Zip (64 / 32bit)

Tags: vba, 7zip

My goal is avoid error msg from VBA debugger. Need to check which version of 7-zip have installed, program files/ or program files (x86):

Trying do simple "IF" function.

```
Dim PathZipProgram As String
strCommand As String

PathZipProgram = "C:\Program Files(x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
If Right(PathZipProgram, 1) Then
    PathZipProgram = PathZipProgram
Else
    PathZipProgram = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
End If

Shell strCommand

strCommand = """" & PathZipProgram & """ a -tzip """
```

VBA cant find 7zip.

Comment: You should better read the registry and get the installation path. It should be stored under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\7-Zip\Path

Comment: without IF function, C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe works, no need to read regstry. only looking for correct IF function how choose 32 bit or 64 bit version

Comment: _Need to check which version of 7zip have installed_ Use the registry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if the file exist with a `function` like this:

```
Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
Dim TestStr As String
    TestStr = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = "" Then
        FileExists = False
    Else
        FileExists = True
    End If
End Function
```

And then use it in your code:

```
Dim PathZipProgram As String
Dim strCommand As String

PathZipProgram = "C:\Program Files(x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"

If Not FileExists(PathZipProgram) Then
    PathZipProgram = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
End If

Shell strCommand

strCommand = """" & PathZipProgram & """ a -tzip """
```

Hope this help as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Installation Path***: 7-Zip could be installed in another disk location (for example the **`D:`** drive, or somewhere else). You do
>   need to read the paths from the registry to be sure. A couple of
>   suggestions below:

---

### **`1. Hacky Version`**

I have put a full script below to use, but you can essentially get what you want the hacky way (make sure the paths actually exists - obviously - maybe use **`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip"`** if there are problems seen):

**`Check File Exists:`**

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists("C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe")) Then
    ' Do Stuff
End If
```

**`Get File Version:`**

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
MsgBox fso.GetFileVersion("C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe")
```

Don't rely on this please. It will fail eventually. Please see below.

---

### **`2. Full Version`**

Here is a full version, the steps you need to make something that has a hope to be reliable. Essentially read paths from registry and take it from there:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002 : strComputer = "."

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set reg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

' 64-bit - Read 7-zip installation path from registry
regpath64 = "SOFTWARE\7-Zip"
reg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regpath64, "Path64", regvalue64
fullpath64 = regvalue64 + "\" + "7z.exe"

If (fso.FileExists(fullpath64)) Then
   MsgBox "7-zip 64-bit: " + fso.GetFileVersion(fullpath64), vbOKOnly, "64-bit:"
End If

' 32-bit - Read 7-zip installation path from registry
regpath32 = "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\7-Zip"
reg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regpath32, "Path", regvalue32
fullpath32 = regvalue32 + "\" + "7z.exe"

If (fso.FileExists(fullpath32)) Then
   MsgBox "7-zip 32-bit: " + fso.GetFileVersion(fullpath32), vbOKOnly, "32-bit:"
End If
```

> ***Disclaimer***: For the 64-bit registry read: there could be a Path and a Path64 entry
>   (I have both). Not sure what earlier and / or later versions will
>   have. Please check.